# Remember DataTables filter, rows per page and page number after post callback

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable

I am experimenting with [DataTable](http://datatables.net/index) library. My main focus is using `Ajax` interface for gathering information I want to display in table.

However my table contains `form` so user is able to change a little bit this table. After user submit a form `php` script is handling inputs and then writes those information into database.

With default configuration of `DataTables` which is :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": '/ajax/database.php'
    } );
} );
```

Things are getting pretty annoying and it is because every time I submit my form fields like page, filter and page count are getting blank. Is there a way to customize it that those fields could get remembered?

I Have tried with assigning `name` attribute to those fields in `jquery.datatables.js` file like:

```
jqFilter.attr('name','sFilter');
```

But for obvious reasons I cant get this variable from `$_POST` variable coz it was not posted in a form.

Can anyone give me a hint how can I implement such thing?

Comment: Why you don't use default layout of page count and rows per page?

Comment: Do You mean why do I use `datatables` at all? It is because table I have is pretty big ( more then 500 rows). I find it pretty easy to use `datatables` in order to create nice and fast pagination and filter (trying to create it by myself caused me some problems)

Comment: No. I mean why you don't use datatables' standard appearance of such elements as page count and rows per page. You don't need care about such control elements since datatables take care on it itself

Comment: The case is that if I am in the page `localhost/test.php` (which have datatables on it) form inside the table contains action for the same page (callback is being handled in the same page) `action='/test.php'`. After submitting the form my filter disappear because page is reloaded. I would like that if filter is set to stay the same after page reload.

Comment: So use AJAX instead of default submitting and your filter won't disappear

Comment: It is not the case. If I fallow your advice and after post I create datatable with ajax source like `/ajax/database.php?filter=filter`. Table will contain only filtered rows, and after deleting filter input I will stay with exactly same output instead of 500+ rows